# Bind mouse button to Control_L or Super_L keys

Tags: linux, mouse, xbindkeys

I'm trying to make mouse button act exact as Control_L or Super_L keys.

In lots of applications (firefox, konsole, etc.) Ctrl+Scroll has special actions like zooming,
so assigning mouse button to modifier key looks very useful.

Also i hope to use mouse button assigned to Super as key for manipulating windows in awesome wm.

So i'm trying to use xbindkeys and xdotool:

```
"xdotool keydown control"
    b:8

"xdotool keyup control"
    release + control + b:8
```

But when i press mouse button #8 xev says:

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x33f, subw 0x0, time 52846491, (-1,166), root:(0,186),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0
```

and when i'm releasing the button:

```
EnterNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x33f, subw 0x0, time 52846655, (-1,166), root:(0,186),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

So applications isn't reciving any key/button notifications (KeyPress and other).

I tried to play with xmodmap, use xte or xvkbd instead of xdotool.

When i tried to assign mouse key to normal key (not modifier) - all works ok.

Also, i tried to call xdotool/xte/xvkbd from another machine by ssh, and that works!

So i absolutely don't know what to try else.
Any ideas?

**Upd**: As far as i understand LeaveNotify and EnterNotify generated by XGrabButton called by xbindkeys, but i still don't know what to do :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I PROPERLY map a keyboard key to a mouse button?](http://superuser.com/questions/883782/how-do-i-properly-map-a-keyboard-key-to-a-mouse-button)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"xdotool keyup control"
  Control + b:8 + release
```

Notice that Control, and all other modifiers for that matter, are capitalized, the modifiers are listed first, and release is last.